# Automatically Insert Row in Another Sheet If a row is added

Tags: excel, vba

I have tables `CustomerTable` in Sheet1, and `SalesTable` in Sheet2.

`CustomerTable` has Customer_Code column (Col A), the formula is:

> =[@[CustomerName ]] &  [@[No order ]]

I want every time a new row is added in `CustomerTable`, the new record of Customer_Code in `CustomerTable`'s Col A is added in `SalesTable`.

Like this:
MA18209 in `CustomerTable`'s Col A appears in the last row of Customer_Code col (Col B) in `SalesTable`.

Code in Sheet1:

```
Sub CopyCustomerCode()
    Dim A As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim otherRow As Long
    otherRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ws.Cells(otherRow, 1).Value = b

End Sub
```

It does nothing.

The desirable state is for Excel to automatically copy the value in Col A, not by clicking a macro button.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `text(month(today()), "00")` ?

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, I actually reworked the formula, so the formula looked as revised. Thanks!

Comment: You declare A as a string and never use it. You never declare otherRow but use it anyway. You pick b out of thin air and expect it to hold a value that will transfer to ws.Cells(otherRow, 1).

Comment: A is the Customer_Code column where the original customer code I want to copy in Sheet1 is. B is the column I actually want to copy to in sheet 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How the row in CustomerTable is added? By inserting new row in the top of the table? Or by writing new info at the bottom and letting excel format is as new row?

You could write a macro for creating new row in CustomerTable and SalesTable at once. For some reason I like then newest entry is on top of the table so I always make button for inserting new rowo in row 2.

This code would add new row to SalesTable with on click_event (if your tables formatted as tables). If you want to avoid on click completely, you could try to use worksheet_change event.

```
 Sub CopyCustomerCode()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    Dim SalesTable As ListObject

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
                                    'your table name here
    Set SalesTable = ws2.ListObjects("Sales_Table")

    'lines for determining last rows
    With SalesTable.Range
        LastRow  .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    End With

    'add new row to bottom of the table
     Set newRow = SalesTable.ListRow.Add

     'copy info from column A in CustomerTable to SalesTable
     With newRow
                              'if inserted row is row 2
         .Range(2) = ws1.Range("A2").Value
     End With

 End Sub
```

Code for inserting new row for CustomerTable in row 2

```
Sub New_Row2()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws1.Range("A2")
     .EntireRow.Insert Shift:xlDown, CopyOrigin:xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
     End With

End Sub
```

EDIT: If new entries in CutomerTable are added in the bottom, you could try finding last row of CustomerTable and using it in `.Range(2)` line.

Code should look something like this (you would have to add it to button_click procedure):

```
Sub CopyCustomerCode()

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim newRow As ListRow
        Dim CustomerTable As ListObject
        Dim SalesTable As ListObject

        Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
                                        'your table name here
        Set SalesTable = ws2.ListObjects("Sales_Table")
                                            'your table name here
        Set CustomerTable = ws1.ListObjects("Cutomer Table")

        'lines for determining last rows
        With SalesTable.Range
            LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
        End With 
        With CustomerTable.Range
             LastCusRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
        End With     

        'add new row to bottom of the table
         Set newRow = SalesTable.ListRow.Add

         'copy info from column A in CustomerTable to SalesTable
         With newRow
             .Range(2) = ws1.Cells(LastCusRow, "A").Value
         End With

     End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gexas, thanks for answering. The row in CustomerCode is added by manually writing new record at the bottom and Excel automatically transformed it into a part of the table. Regarding this line of code: .Range(2) = ws1.Range("A2").Value, what if the table is dynamic and keep expanding?

Comment: As I said, my provided code works if for every new entry in CutomerTable you insert new row and add entry to row 2. To make it dynamic, you could try to find last row of CustomerTable and use it `.Range(1) = ws1.Cells(LastCusRow, "A").Value` I'll edit my answer to include additional code.

Comment: Is this possible without VBA, but just functions?

Comment: Well VBA is basically custom functions. To my knowledge Excel does not have this kind of default functionality to include row in another table every time row is added somewhere else. Even if it would have it, my guess it would not be simple because it need quite specific instructions.

Comment: The variable names should be `ws1` and `ws2` in the first two lines of `CopyCustomerCode()`.